# Will postgresql allow any sort of concatenation for (double quoted) identifier names?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Most of my constraint names are concise and short, but a few of them are long and including those on a single line exceeds the code style conventions I am working with.

Without thinking about it, I just did a line break and a double pipe, as so:

```
history         uint4                              constraint "[tablename] The beginning of history must be sooner " ||
                                                       "than the current day" check (history <= hdate)
```

This of course fails, because it's an identifier and not a string literal. I understand why it fails, and this bums me out because I'm almost certain that there's no way to break and continue the identifier on a second line.

Am I wrong? Is there a trick here? It seems like I should be able to get away with a `\` at the end of the line, but then the continuation can't be indented (since those spaces would be part of the identifier name).

Answer (score 1):

You can `execute` a statement, which contains the original command, formatting, function calls etc. You may want to put the constraint in an `alter table` statement instead of wrapping the entire table creation statement in the `execute`

```
do $$ BEGIN
 EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE tex (' ||
    'hdate int, ' ||
    'history int constraint "[tablename] The beginning of history must be sooner ' ||
                            'than the current day" check (history <= hdate));';
end $$;

\d tex
                 Table "public.tex"
 Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 hdate   | integer |           |          |
 history | integer |           |          |
Check constraints:
    "[tablename] The beginning of history must be sooner than the cu" CHECK (history <= hdate)
```

PS: though the text seems too long and will be truncated, regardless of the string concatenation

Comment: I only just noticed that I exceeded 63 chars with it... but it'd still be a problem under that length.